# Synonyms for (information) "system" and "applications"?

Tags: synonyms

As the title asks, what are some synonyms for "system(s)" in the context of "information systems" and software development. Similarly, what are some synonyms for "applications", as in, "...developed applications in `programming language`..."

Answer (score 1):

Package, freeware, software, app, API, routine, etc but you can't just use them (all) interchangeably

For example:

> I developed an API in python

is not the same as in

> I developed an OS in python

sources: [1](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/software), [2](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/computer-software)

Comment: nice, these are useful when the context of discussion is open source or mobile development. Some synonyms when the context is "enterprise software" would be useful, too.